# SwiftUI blurred view bumper edge

Tags: ios, swift, user-interface, swiftui

I have 2 blurred that move together on a drag. If the drag is complete their upper and bottom edge is on the same height but there is still a visible line between those two views. I think it's due to the nature of the blur but I don't know how to modify the blur itself if this is the problem. Has anyone an idea how to make these two views to a merged view (without an additional view as an overlay)?

Here is a Video of the description:
https://youtu.be/sjpC9ZqIIj4

This is my BlurView:

```
import SwiftUI

struct BlurView: UIViewRepresentable {

    var style: UIBlurEffect.Style
    
    func makeUIView(context: Context) -> UIVisualEffectView{
        
        let view = UIVisualEffectView(effect: UIBlurEffect(style: style))
        
        return view
    }
    
    func updateUIView(_ uiView: UIVisualEffectView, context: Context) {
        
    }
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and see: [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). I would think you could remove the blur when the views meet, but without an MRE, it is hard to say. Also, SwiftUI has a blur. Why not use that?

Comment: The things you are trying solve with having two views one in top and another in bottom is impossible! And also there is no issue with UIBlurEffect! It is the nature of UIBlurEffect that needs those extra space to make Blur happen! and once those are coming near together they take and put effect on each other!